# Append php file to footer

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I have javascript in my php file. and I want to load it in footer. Is any method for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'insert_my_js_to_footer');
function insert_my_js_to_footer(){
?>
  <script>
    // your script here.
  </script>
<?php
};
```

**UPDATE:**

And if you want to append the php file itself then you can try this.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'insert_php_file_to_footer');
function insert_php_file_to_footer(){
    include( 'your-php-file.php' );
};
```

Comment: This is what i'm exactly looking. thank you.